# Selecting 'DATE' fields in mysql by month and day with comparison

Tags: mysql, date, doctrine-orm

Trying to select a closest previous and next holiday from the database. Say, *New Year's Day* is always at the 1st of January, and *New Year's Eve* is at the 31st of December. Current year is completely irrelevant, so I'm trying to select previous holiday by day and month (*New Year's Eve*) with the following `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`holidayDate`, "%m-%d") < "01-01"
```

It gives NULL. I was expecting that it would drop through and will look in the previous month, December, but...

Tried a lot of different ways of doing it, but still no success.

P.S.: Cannot use `TIMESTAMP` in this case...

Comment: Are you storing the holidaydate as a date or a string? What are you using for the year?

Comment: Field type is date. I've made comparison against different types of input, including formatted DateTime, and most of them work well except for falling back to previous month of year (or next month). Year is stored as zeroes, like '0000-01-01', but I've tried current year as well.

Comment: Okay, I gave it a shot. It works on SQL Fiddle, so hopefully it helps you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's returning null is because there isn't anything less than '01-01'. The query doesn't wrap around to the beginning.

What I would do is write a case statement that checks to see if you are at the earliest holiday.

If you are the earliest holiday, then you can select the latest holiday (a way of wrapping around).
If you are not the earliest holiday, then you need to select the one before it. I did this by ordering them in descending date, and limiting it to 1. (Effectively grabbing the holiday occurring before the current date.)

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM calendar
WHERE   
    CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT((SELECT MIN(c.holidayDate) FROM calendar c), '%m-%d')
        THEN holidayDate = (SELECT MAX(c.holidayDate) FROM calendar c)
    ELSE
        DATE_FORMAT(holidayDate, '%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d')
    END
ORDER BY holidayDate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07e7c/25) example. I created two queries. One that uses the current date (seen above) and one that has Jan 1st hard coded to show that the case statement does work. I've only added certain holidays to test.

Comment: This looks like a decent solution. I'll give it a try and spend some time rewriting it on Doctrine. Then I'll come up with final conclusion : )

Comment: Good luck! If it doesn't work let me know and I can tweak it.

Comment: Well, can't find any better solution. However the query gets really monstrous when you need a simple calendar with current, next and previous holiday. Also, Doctrine does not support `CASE` or `IF` statements (just why?!), so you have to install extensions or do it native-SQL.

Comment: @Grimv01k I've never used Doctrine, I've tried googling some stuff but I'm beat. Sorry I couldn't help you. In certain DBMS this would work.

Comment: You've helped greatly! You can always do it natively in ORM's and then map it to you're entity, so not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If two queries are acceptable for you:

```
SELECT max(holidayDate) as prev_holiday from calendar where holidayDate < now();
SELECT min(holidayDate) as next_holiday from calendar where holidayDate > now();
```